How to make grid or flex item stays the same length, without content overflowing it's container or overlapping?
How do you make sure that the image or video keeps their length?
I am new to HTML and CSS and I am trying to make a project of a YouTube clone, by modifying the source code of a course. This is a screenshot. However, every time I use image other than the course's source code, it breaks and I can't understand why?
I tried using flex, but items are overflowing.
How do you make sure that a grid or flex item stays the same length, without content overflowing it's container?


.thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
}

.video-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.video-info-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr;
}

.profile-picture {
  width: 36px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.thumbnail-row {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  position: relative;
  /* object-fit: cover; */
}

.thumbnail-row {
    object-fit: cover;
}

.video-author,
.video-stats {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgb(96, 96, 96);
}

.video-author {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.video-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 16px;
  row-gap: 40px;
}



@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .video-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 751px) and (max-width: 999px) {
  .video-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .video-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 600px){
    .video-grid {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr ;
    }
  }

.video-time {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: black;5
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 5px;
}
<main>
  <section class="video-grid">
    <div class="video-preview">
      <div class="thumbnail-row">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="images/selmon-bhai.jpeg">
        <div class="video-time">14:20</div>
      </div>
      <div class="video-info-grid">
        <div class="channel-picture">
          <img class="profile-picture" src="images/hrithik.png">
        </div>
        <div class="video-info">
          <p class="video-title">
            Selmon Bhai ne mumbai me bacchi ko bachaaya. &#129402; &#129402;
          </p>
          <p class="video-author">
            Marques Brownlee
          </p>
          <p class="video-stats">
            3.4M views &#183; 6 months ago
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video-preview">
      <div class="thumbnail-row">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="images/selmon-bhai.jpeg">
        <div class="video-time">14:20</div>
      </div>
      <div class="video-info-grid">
        <div class="channel-picture">
          <img class="profile-picture" src="images/hrithik.png">
        </div>
        <div class="video-info">
          <p class="video-title">
            Selmon Bhai ne mumbai me bacchi ko bachaaya. &#129402; &#129402;
          </p>
          <p class="video-author">
            Marques Brownlee
          </p>
          <p class="video-stats">
            3.4M views &#183; 6 months ago
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</main>




Set the img width to be 100% of the container,  and set the container to be same length as the others, Since the img is a square and not in landscape like the others you will need to adjust its Height as well,
Try something like:
.thumbnail{
width:100%;
height:50%; //adjust it to your needs please
}
